# Why can't I move notes from my "On My iPhone" to iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud, notes.app, iphone

I have an iPhone SE running iOS 9.3.3.  I use the Notes app extensively to share between my iMac running Mavericks, and my phone and iPads.

Recently I accidentally moved 4 notes from iCloud, to the phone itself.  I thought this was trivial and I could just move the notes back, but I cannot.  There is no option to do so.

First, I should say that I *am* running the "new" Notes app (the one with doodles, photos, etc.)  Second, when I go into my local folder on the phone and hit Edit, I  get the "Move All" option, but iCloud is not presented as an option to move to, only my local phone and a New Folder option.  There is no way presented to move the notes to iCloud, either en masse or individually.

I have tried turning Notes off/on in iCloud, as well as signing out & back in to iCloud, without success.

How can I get these notes to move back to iCloud again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using a Mac or iCloud.com, I think the best way is to simply copy and paste the contents of each note into a new note that is on iCloud. Thankfully, you only have four notes, so it's not too time intensive to do.

Comment: But I can use a mac or iCloud, so how would they help?  I want to know in case this happens in the future with more notes.

Comment: I suppose if it's local to your iPhone, a Mac or iCloud wouldn't help very much. I would copy paste your notes over and disable the "On My iPhone" account.